# what is the redirect for .htaccess from a wordpress url ending in / to .html

Tags: .htaccess

We have had to take a step back after many problems with a wordpress site. 
I now face the challenge that the wordpress url was for example mysite.com/product/this-product/ and the site structure is now mysite.com/product/this-product.html

I have read lots of examples of how to redirect but cant find anything to match this situation?

Any help would be strongly appreciated

Comment: Could you share what you have tried?

Comment: I have not got as far as testing any code yet, I can see that if I try and use a wildcard for anything in the /product/ directory that will cause a loop since the .html files are in here. I wondered about using a index file in the directory with a .php redirect, but with 5000 products this would not be practical. I assume that since the url was previously written by wordpress ending in a / the .php to .html redirect will not work.

Comment: I think I need to work out the 301? redirect for:-
(1) the url ends in / and is in the product folder (2) it should be rewritten as product folder $1.html. I assume this would be added to the root .htaccess